# Exclude files from auto update of a sideloaded UWP App

Tags: file, uwp, auto-update, sideloading

Iam using an offline Vector-Basemap (Size: 1.35GB) in my UWP-Application.

Currently, in 'developing'-Stage, iam using a filepicker to load the map from disk, but in a later version of the app, i want to include the map in the app solution, to preload the map at app-start.

Because of the fact, that the content of the basemap is only updating every 4-6 months, i want to know if it is possible to exclude the basemap from auto update?

Like:

| AppVersion | Auto-Update (Sideload) | AppSize |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1.0.0.1 | include map | ~1.5GB |
| 1.0.0.2 | - | ~150MB |
| 1.0.0.3 | - | ~150MB |
| 1.0.0.4 | - | ~150MB |
| 1.0.0.5 | update map | ~1.5GB |

Thanks for your time!!

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

> it is possible to exclude the basemap from auto update?

No, it is not possible to do that. A similar way to implement what you want might be that you could manually control the update of the basemap. You could exclude the basemap from your sideload package. Then put the basemap somewhere else and download the basemap when the local basemap needs to be updated.